# How to make facebook comment box width 100% and responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

The same question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862256/how-to-make-facebook-comment-box-width-100`
I tried all the answers, but it doesn't work anymore. Looks like Facebook changed some stuff a little bit.

Comment: I liked 2014 in your question...

Comment: well explained .. :D :D

Comment: :) I tried all the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862256/how-to-make-facebook-comment-box-width-100 :) It doesn't work anymore :) so I add 2014 )

Comment: I'm wondering the same. It stopped working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This <strike>is</strike> was a facebook bug, check it out here:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/

<strike>The only available workaround is just using javascript.</strike>

Later edit: Bug fixed: You have to write: `data-width="100%"`

> The width of the plugin. Either a pixel value or the literal 100% for
>   fluid width. The mobile version of the Comments plugin ignores the
>   width parameter, and instead has a fluid width of 100%.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Comment: Bug fixed! Just add data-width="100%"

Comment: Weird - not working for me. If I use 100% for fluid, the comments box doesn't show up at all. I've had to use javascript to resize it.

Comment: I get this issue randomly, sometimes would load at 100% and other times very narrow.. havent been able to fix it

Answer (score 11):

With reference to https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/173395380238318/

Facebook comment plugin, they keep on updating new stuff but sometimes it ends up to a new bug.

So simple CSS will resolve the width issues.

```
/*Fb Comments Width Fix*/
.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop, .fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop span, .fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop iframe {
            max-width: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
 }
```

**Note: Make sure you use !important. Without important, it will not work as excepted.**

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(".fb-comments").attr("data-width", $(".fb-comments").parent().width());
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            resizeiframe();
        });

    function resizeiframe() {
        var src = $('.fb-comments iframe').attr('src').split('width='),
            width = $(".fb-comments").parent().width();

        $('.fb-comments iframe').attr('src', src[0] + 'width=' + width);
    }
```

Jquery Workaround,

Source : https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/
Comment by : Milap Bhojak

Answer (score 1):

Facebook added another width 550px on .pluginSkinLight > div

add this to your css 
.pluginSkinLight > div {width: 100% !important;}

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a solution in response to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22328835/2544386

The issue is that within the iframe, Facebook can change the CSS, classes, add fixed widths etc.
But if you use JS in a smart way by manipulating the tag in your HTML before it is parsed by Facebook, I believe it really reduces the chances of it being broken again if Facebook change something at their end.

Answer (score 1):

facebook changed fb-comments plug in and now you can use data-width="100%"

you dont need any of style or js code.

```
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" 
data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the simplest way without programming. No complications.

You just do it like always (with the facebook's code box), then open Inspect Element on the browser (right-click any element on the page and select this option) and click on the like box `<iframe></iframe>` and copy it on your code (only the iframe!). It works exactly like the other code.

Now remove the width of the iframe, or write `width:100%` on it.

Just like this:

```
<iframe name="f15e6cf8a8" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like_box Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/yourentirepage" style="border:none;visibility:visible;height:541px" class=""></iframe>
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple JS workaround

1) Add id ("fb_chat" in this sample) to the FB comments div:

`<div id="fb_chat" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://your_url" data-numposts="30" data-colorscheme="light"></div>`

2) Use this JS block (replace 'chat_body' to your comments parent container):

`<script type="text/javascript">
            var fb_chat = document.getElementById('fb_chat');
            var container_width = document.getElementById('chat_body').clientWidth * 0.985;
            var attr = document.createAttribute('data-width');
            attr.nodeValue = container_width.toString();
            fb_chat.attributes.setNamedItem(attr);
 </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `data-width="100%"` does make the comments 100% width, but still not exactly fluid like you would expect. They will fill a container, but only on load and will not resize when the window is resized. In order to do that add this to your css:

`.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span, iframe.fb_ltr { 
    width: 100% !important; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

For solve this problem remove "data-width" from `<div class="fb-comments"...`

FB automaticly will put 100%

or delete `data-mobile="auto"`